# SQL - Group fields into a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query which gets all public transport subscriptions. A subscription can have multiple related companies. So I wanted to do with my query is to get all the subscriptions and instead of creating a row each time I have a related company, the companies should by group into one column. Is it possible to do that?

Here's the query :

```
SELECT pts.Id_PublicTransportSubscription, 
       pts.Amount, 
       ptc.Name
FROM bm_PublicTransportSubscriptions AS pts 
  INNER JOIN bm_PublicTransportSubscriptionByCompany AS ptsbc 
  ON pts.Id_PublicTransportSubscription = ptsbc.Id_PublicTransportSubscription 
  INNER JOIN bm_PublicTransportCompanies AS ptc 
  ON ptsbc.Id_PublicTransportCompany = ptc.Id_PublicTransportCompany
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Please take a look at [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/273330/1231866).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it but I'm using SQL Server 2008.